# relationship between determinant of a matrix and that of its cofactor matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

how to show that $\frac{det A^C}{det A}$ = (A$^C$)$^C$*A$^{-1}$ ? In which A$^c$ is the cofactor matrix of A. Specifically, A is an n by n matrix, the cofactor matrix of A denoted by A$^C$ is that (A$^C$)$_{ij}$ = (-1)$^{i+j}$detA$_{(j)(i)}$.  A$_{(j)(i)}$ is the (n-1) by (n-1) matrix by deleting jth row and ith column.

Comment: I'd start with the fact that $A\cdot \text{adj}A=\det A \cdot I$, and then I'd apply the formula to $\text{adj}A$ instead of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adjugate of $A$ is the transpose of your $A^{C}$ and is easier to work with.

From the usual (Laplace) expansion of a determinant along a given row/column we have that for any square matrix $A$ 
$$
A\cdot\text{adj}A=\det A\cdot I.
$$
Applying this to the matrix $\text{adj}A$ we have
$$
\text{adj}A\cdot\text{adj}\ \text{adj}A=\det \text{adj}A\cdot I.
$$

Now $A$ and $\text{adj}A$ commute, as their product is scalar. So
assuming that $A$ is invertible (as you do) we get
$$
A^{-1}\cdot\text{adj}\ \text{adj}A=(\det A)^{-1} \det \text{adj}A\cdot I.
$$

This is what you want: the transposes don't matter in the determinant, and cancel out in the repeated adjugate. (Again, $A^{-1}$ commutes with $\text{adj}\ \text{adj}A$ since their product is scalar.)